# trying to read the rules using the changeset.xml from guvnor results in error

Tags: drools, eclipse-indigo, drools-guvnor

I tried to load the package from the Guvnor using the following piece of code :-

```
    KnowledgeBuilder kbuilder = KnowledgeBuilderFactory.newKnowledgeBuilder();
    kbuilder.add(ResourceFactory.newClassPathResource("GenderFact.xml"),ResourceType.CHANGE_SET);
    System.out.println("fair trial");
    KnowledgeBuilderErrors errors = kbuilder.getErrors();
    if (errors.size() > 0) {
        for (KnowledgeBuilderError error: errors) {
            System.err.println(error);
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Could not parse knowledge.");
    }
    KnowledgeBase kbase = KnowledgeBaseFactory.newKnowledgeBase();
    kbase.addKnowledgePackages(kbuilder.getKnowledgePackages());
    return kbase;
```

and the contents of the GenderFact.xml are :-

```
<change-set xmlns="http://drools.org/drools-5.0/change-set"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xs:schemaLocation="http://drools.org/drools-5.0/change-set http://anonsvn.jboss.org/repos/labs/labs/jbossrules/trunk/drools-api/src/main/resources/change-set-1.0.0.xsd">
<add>
    <resource
        source="http://localhost:8080/drools-guvnor/org.drools.guvnor.Guvnor/package/MyLastTrial/LATEST/"
        type="PKG" basicAuthentication="disabled" username="admin" password="admin" />
</add>
```

When I tried to execute this from Eclipse , I get the following error :-

> java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.InvalidClassException: org.drools.rule.MVELDialectRuntimeData; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 5166066541265170937, local class serialVersionUID = -64624826351992706
>       at org.drools.compiler.PackageBuilder.addKnowledgeResource(PackageBuilder.java:705)
>       at org.drools.compiler.PackageBuilder.addPackageFromChangeSet(PackageBuilder.java:772)
>       at org.drools.compiler.PackageBuilder.addKnowledgeResource(PackageBuilder.java:694)
>       at org.drools.builder.impl.KnowledgeBuilderImpl.add(KnowledgeBuilderImpl.java:45)
>       at org.drools.builder.impl.KnowledgeBuilderImpl.add(KnowledgeBuilderImpl.java:34)
>       at com.sample.DroolsTest.readKnowledgeBase(DroolsTest.java:43)
>       at com.sample.DroolsTest.main(DroolsTest.java:26)
>   Caused by: java.io.InvalidClassException: org.drools.rule.MVELDialectRuntimeData; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 5166066541265170937, local class serialVersionUID = -64624826351992706
>       at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.initNonProxy(Unknown Source)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(Unknown Source)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(Unknown Source)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.HashMap.readObject(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(Unknown Source)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(Unknown Source)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
>       at org.drools.rule.DialectRuntimeRegistry.readExternal(DialectRuntimeRegistry.java:59)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readExternalData(Unknown Source)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
>       at org.drools.rule.Package.readExternal(Package.java:208)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readExternalData(Unknown Source)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
>       at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
>       at org.drools.core.util.DroolsStreamUtils.streamIn(DroolsStreamUtils.java:205)
>       at org.drools.core.util.DroolsStreamUtils.streamIn(DroolsStreamUtils.java:189)
>       at org.drools.compiler.PackageBuilder.addPackageFromInputStream(PackageBuilder.java:781)
>       at org.drools.compiler.PackageBuilder.addKnowledgeResource(PackageBuilder.java:692)
>       ... 6 more

Preconditions :-

- I use Guvnor 5.3 with jboss AS 7.0.
- Both the client and the server are sharing the same jre7.
- Drools runtime 5.3 in Eclipse Indigo (Service Release 2)

Requesting for a workaround ...

Answer (score 4):

Drools related jars used in java project are NOT of same version as used in GUvnor 5.3.
Use jars from Guvnor 5.3 into your java project.
It will solve problem. :)